# 2D Perlin Noise looking odd

Tags: c, noise, perlin-noise

I'm not sure if my Perlin Noise generator is functioning properly, the noise it generates looks very different from the images I see online. Mine looks too homogeneous (these are three different images):

[image][image][image]

Whereas what I usually see is something like:

[image]

My code is basically:

```
/* Get the coord of the top-left gradient of the grid (y, x) falls in */
int j = floor(x);
int i = floor(y);
/* Get the distance (y, x) is from it */
double dx = x-j;
double dy = y-i;
/* Influence of (g)radient(i)(j) (starting at the top-left one) */
double g00 = dot(grad(hashes, hsize, grads, i, j), dy, dx);
double g01 = dot(grad(hashes, hsize, grads, i, j+1), dy, dx-1);
double g10 = dot(grad(hashes, hsize, grads, i+1, j), dy-1, dx);
double g11 = dot(grad(hashes, hsize, grads, i+1, j+1), dy-1, dx-1);
/* Interpolate the influences using the blending function */
/* Linear interpol the top 2 */
double lt = lerp(g00, g01, fade(dx));
/* Linear interpol the bottom 2 */
double lb = lerp(g10, g11, fade(dx));
/* Linear interpol lb lt, completing the bilienear interpol */
return lerp(lt, lb, fade(dy));
```

[Complete code](http://pastebin.com/nibewGjh). It's based mainly on [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf) tutorial. I'm using [this script](http://pastebin.com/sMJTeF0y) to draw the csv file.

I understand the basics, but after reading several "tutorials" that usually contradict each other and the "reference implementation" which is not very readable I have a few doubts. The `(x, y)` points being interpolated should be in what interval? As I understand it, it should be `[0, GRID_SIZE-1]` (e.g. `[0, 255]` if using a pre-computed table with 256 random values). However, my code only results in reasonably good looking images when `(x, y)` is mapped to `[0, 1]`, and I see some implementations online that map it to `[0, 255]` no matter the grid size. I'm also unsure if I'm picking the gradients correctly from the table.

Comment: Looks like perlin noise, just too scaled. Have a look at M Oehm answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normalize your pixel coordinates to the whole image. You should normalize it to the size of your simplex grid.

So instead of your code for the inner loop:

```
  double x = j/(double)w;
  double y = i/(double)h;
```

do:

```
  double x = j / gridsize;
  double y = i / gridsize;
```

where the grid size is an additional parameter, for example:

```
  double gridsize = 32.0;
```

(It should probably be chosen to fit evenly into the image dimensions.)